Grouping rows based on Font
Im trying to group rows on excel based on if the contents of the cell is not underlined.
Here is how i want the code to perform:
Find a cell that is NOT underlined
group that cell with all the ones under it until you find the next cell that is not underlined
Then restart until last row with content
Here is the code i have so far:
Sub GroupCellsSameFormat() 

Dim r As Integer, lr As Integer, startr As Integer, endr As Integer 
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  

For r = 2 To lr
      If Range("A" & r).Font.Underline = False Then
          If startr = 0 Then
              startr = r + 1
          Else
              endr = r - 1
              Range("A" & startr & ":A" & endr).Rows.Group
              startr = r + 1
          End If
      End If
  Next r
   Range("A" & startr & ":A" & lr).Rows.Group

End Sub

But the last statement " Range("A" & startr & ":A" & lr).Rows.Group " is giving me the following error
Runtime Error '1004'
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed
Can someone help me with this :)

Pls validate both startr and lr are non-zero.


If the contents of the cell is not underlined, the Underline property returns xlNone instead of False

Microsoft documentation:

Font.Underline property (Excel)


XlUnderlineStyle enumeration (Excel)

Try
If Range("A" & r).Font.Underline = xlNone Then



The condition below in your code is never met, so when Range("A" & startr & ":A" & lr).Rows.Group is executed, startr is 0. This is the cause of the runtime error.

If Range("A" & r).Font.Underline = False Then

